# org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query Params wrong result

Tags: spring-boot, sqlite, jpa

Hi I have a problem with result of this method:

```
@Query(value = "select * from Mail where sent_Flag = 0 and scheduled < '?1'", nativeQuery = true)
    public List<Mail> getToSend(Long timestamp);
```

If I put value 0 or current timestamp result is the same (returns all records like scheduled 1=1), If I try to run it via SQL directly everything works, where is a problem?

I'm using SQLite and springboot

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, but works for"

```
select * from Mail where sent_Flag = 0 and scheduled between 0 and ?
```

Comment: It works because you used `'` around the `?` in your first solution.